# what is gulp.js and how it is related to npm

Tags: npm, gulp

I am new to the development based on java-script frameworks. I want to understand gulp, npm. Somewhere, I read that these are open source client side development tool but I could not get more insight on this. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a task runner, written in JavaScript to be run in a nodeJs environment. You need a package manager like npm to install it. Npm comes with nodejs.

[An Introduction to Gulp.js](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-gulp-js/)

It is an application doing things like the following, instead of you. You need only to code once the instructions and run it.

Compressing new and modified images; compiling Sass to CSS code; code linting and validation; concatenating and minifying CSS and JavaScript files; deploying files to development, staging and production servers.

Comment: What is a task runner, Is it like Timer job or something?